# Torque and Current Frequency Relationship in Lorentz force

Tags: frequency, electromagnetism, electromagnetic

Lorentz force equation shows us that current is proportional to the force. Is it safe to assume that the force generated by an AC current at 60Hz will always have the same frequency? In other words, as the current increases and deceases (sinusoidal) the force will follow the same pattern at the same rate.

Would this be true if the current flow had a circular shape or any non-linear shape? The reason I ask is because Maxwell is giving me torque plots with frequencies twice the current's frequency. I find this odd.

Edit: Here is a simple simulation of a wire with 100A RMS passing through. The plots shows the current and the torque around the wire. This proves to me that the frequency of the Torque is twice of the Current.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's generating the stator field? Is this a field coil brushed motor (aka "universal" motor)?

Comment: Your wire is carrying 140A but only producing 19 _micro_ NM of torque? Current goes positive and negative but the torque is all negative? What external magnetic field is being applied?

Comment: I do not have an external field. It is just a wire with 100 rms passing through. I realized this is a bad representation of lorentz force law since it depends on an external field. These forces I'm plotting (uNM), why is it all negative or all postivie depending on the direction I plot? I thought the force would change with direction of current.